# How to get html from partial view from within controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an e-commerce type application and when the user submits their payment I want to display a receipt page as well as a copy of the receipt in an email.  Since the HTML for the receipt page and the receipt email is the same I would like use the View to generate HTML for the email.

How can I get the html from a view from within the controller?

Comment: Look at Postal - http://aboutcode.net/postal/

Comment: Postal looks cool, but can I use it and still send the email myself?  We have custom email sending utility that does some queuing stuff that I need to keep in place

Comment: I swear this exact question was asked yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/). But because you mentioned emailing views you should definitely take a look at [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). Scott Hanselman also [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx) about it.